# How to get threads to wait and execute when others a ready (multi lane bridge Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

just having an issue with a multi lane bridge problem. So the criteria is that there is a 2 lane bridge with objects on either side. The objects from each side can only cross in pairs and can only cross with the object of the same side (ie Object from side A can only cross from another object of side A).

Each object in this situation is a thread and the bridge a Semaphore. I have been able to make sure 2 objects cross at a time and the others wait for both to cross before another pair go, but my issue lies with checking to make sure they are both from the same side.

Comment: Cyclic Barrier comes to mind

Comment: Thanks for that, just checked them out and I think that will be very helpful.